# Get reflog of Azure devops repo?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-reflog

One of our refs has been moved to a commit where it shouldn't be, presumably because someone did a merge in the wrong direction or something like that.

To sort this out (see what actually happened) it would be a great help to see a reflog for that ref, but from the devops cloud repo itself, as opposed to showing it for any specific developer's local repo.

Is there any way I can get a reflog from the Azure devops cloud repo?

I understand that there's no git command that can be executed on a developer machine that can get it for the remote/cloud repo. I also found that Azure devops offers a git api, but for refs all i can find is [calls to list refs, modify/create/delete refs, and lock/unlock refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

How about the built-in History view in Azure devops repo? We can view all merges in it.

[image]

**Update**:

You can add a powershell task to a pipeline, run `git checkout master` and `git reflog show --all` commands to get reflog.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it just shows the commit history. If I have branch A and derive branch B from there. Then make commits to B, and then merge B to A, the merge will just fast-forward A to the last commit of B. There won't be any record of that operation, who did it or when it happened, and most importantly, there's no way to see where A pointed before that (which is what it should be reset to, probably). All I can see is the commit history and that A and B point to the same commit.

Comment: You can add a powershell task to a pipeline, run `git checkout master` and `git reflog show --all` commands to get reflog.

Comment: Oh, so a powershell task has access to the cloud git repo? Interesting. Would be worth a try. Unfortunately I already chose a "qualified guess" approach, so I have left the actual problem behind for now. Will keep this in mind for future needs. Thanks! (I'll be sure to mark this as correct answer when I've tried it).

Comment: Looking forward to your test result. :)